# Nginx fails to restart via Ansible

Tags: nginx, ansible, vagrant

I have a task in a playbook that tries to restart nginx via a handler as per usual:

```
  name: restart nginx  
  service: name=nginx state=restarted
```

It gaves me this following error:

```
RUNNING HANDLER [webtier : restart nginx] **************************************
fatal: [vagrant]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to restart service nginx: Failed to restart nginx.service: Connection timed out\nSee system logs and 'systemctl status nginx.service' for details.\n"}
```

However until last time **sudo: yes** command was working. and the above error was not coming.

But this time, by adding **sudo: yes** command

```
  name: restart nginx  
  service: name=nginx state=restarted
  sudo: yes
```

Gives following error:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: service, sudo

The error appears to be in '/Users/mac/Documents/GitHub/petalandstem/ansible/roles/webtier/handlers/main.yml': line 28, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: restart nginx
  ^ here

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

How to restart nginx successfully ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is either INI

```yaml
    - name: restart nginx  
      service: name=nginx state=restarted
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
```

or YAML

```yaml
    - name: restart nginx  
      service:
        name: nginx
        state: restarted
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
```

See [Understanding privilege escalation: become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation-become).

Answer (score 0):

- Ansible 1.x: `sudo: yes`
- Ansible 2.x: `become: yes`

That's because the become_method is a choice now but the default is "sudo".

```
--become-method=BECOME_METHOD
    privilege escalation method to use (default=sudo), 
    valid choices: [ sudo | su | pbrun | pfexec | doas | dzdo | ksu | runas | machinectl ]
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue
this happened to me because **httpd** was already running on **port 80**
so i had to **stop** the **httpd** **service**

```
$ service httpd stop
```

then try the **ansible**-**playbook**

Answer (score -2):

First don't edit the files in sites-enabled, but create links and edit in sites-available.

For me the problem was in sites-enabled folder.
When you delete the default site from sites-available folder, you need to delete the link from sites-enabled.

After deleting the default link from sites-enabled for me worked.